# Zenith Data Systems laptop with Timer Interrupt Error

Tags: interrupt, 8088, zenith-supersport

I have an old Zenith “laptop” that runs on an 80c88 processor, and apparently was manufactured around 1985. It’s quite a beast of a laptop - size and weight, rather than computing power!.

Unfortunately it fails at boot with a Timer Interrupt Error.
[image]

I’ve started digging for any info that will help with a fix, with not much to find on the error or generally on the computer itself. The manuals have some basic hardware descriptions, but I’ve not found any schematics or technical fault finding manuals.
If anyone has any hints or tips, your advice would be much appreciated. Also, if there are any other online forums that are better for this kind of question, appreciate the info.

I’ve already posted on a retro computer forum on Facebook, with some good advice for fault finding, however the fix remains elusive, so looking to the experts on this forum for any further advice.
[Discussion on FB forum](https://www.facebook.com/groups/retrocomputers/permalink/3798720313491155/)

Appreciate any help getting a fix for this.
Thanks
Rob

Comment: My first suspicion on anything really old like this is a CMOS backup battery.  These often were used to keep the BIOS settings in CMOS RAM and also to run an RTC.  Dead battery means no RTC which ultimately means no timer interrupt which the startup may be expecting.  Try opening the case and see if you can find a battery that can be replaced.

Comment: @jwh20, The (18.2Hz) Timer Interrupt in an 8088 PC compatible is not generated by the RTC but by the 8253 Programmable Interval Timer (or a derivative), counter 0, which might be a good place to start looking for clues as to what’s wrong.

Comment: thanks guys. Yes, I've not found any batteries for RTC on the board. There are 8259 and 8254 chips that are part of this circuit.

Comment: I've done some basic checks for an output on the IR0 line of the 8259 (there was), but I don't have an Oscilloscope (or skills) to get in to the detail of interrupt signal timing. Keen to learn though.

Comment: The 8254 is equivalent to an 8253. Lacking a scope you could try one of the cheap 8-channel logic analyzers (and learn a lot in the process).

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll need to get an Oscilliscope (or logic analyser) I think, how would I know what the correct outputs should be though?

Comment: One other piece of news, I found that there is a multi-key combination that aborts the BIOS self tests, and takes you to the built in Monitor function. It recognises the key combination, goes to Monitor, but doesn't function any further. Any key presses do nothing but emit an error beep. Does this give any further indications of the fault cause?